# Hidden contain in a scrollable table has no display none in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in FF and IE because the contain that I don't show in a table body via vertical scroll makes appear the page scroll. This does not happen in Chrome and Safari. This is my basic code:

```css
.div-table-content {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 1082px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div id="container" class="div-table-content">
    <table id="tb" class="table table-bordered table-no-border table-hover table-condensed">
      <tbody id="bodyTb">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I fill the tablebody via JS. If this contain takes a higher vertical space that the height of the container has, the scroll of the table appears but also appears a scroll on the page and that's not correct.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: provide a jsfilddle

Comment: snippet of your code is behaving normal, where is problem, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/47qmu4tw/1/ I think that the problem only will be visible running in pure FF or IE, not in a emulator like jsfiddle.